# How to traverse associative array in PHP and access both key and data

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to traverse an associative array in PHP and access both the key and the data in the most efficient way possible. This has got to be a duplicate, but I can't find a "best practice" example anywhere on SO that says "this is the definitive way to do it in PHP."

Example:

```
$array = ["one"=>"un", "two"=>"deux", "three"=>"trois"];
foreach ($array as $value){
    $key = array_search($value, $array);
    print_r($key);
    print_r($value);
}
```

This is horrible; it traverses once per iteration when it searches for the key. Is there a better way to access the index of the array?

Edit:
5.28 seconds for 100k iterations on my machine. `php -a`

```
$start=microtime(true);for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){foreach($array as $value){$key = array_search($value, $array);print_r($key);print_r($value);}}$stop=microtime(true);$time = $stop - $start; print_r($time);
```

5.3 seconds for:

```
$start=microtime(true);for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){foreach($array as $key=>$value){print_r($key);print_r($value);}}$stop=microtime(true);$time = $stop - $start; print_r($time);
```

So no performance boost? The lack of difference is still there for a larger array:

```
$array = ["one"=>"un", "two"=>"deux", "three"=>"trois", "four"=>"quatre", "five"=>"cinq", "six"=>"six", "seven"=>"sept", "eight"=>"huit", "nine"=>"neuf", "ten"=>"dix"];
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` ?

Comment: `$start=microtime(true);for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){foreach($array as $key=>$value){print_r($key);print_r($value);}}$stop=microtime(true);$time = $stop - $start; print_r($time);` takes 5.3s on my machine. This isn't faster than `array_search`! Is it because the array is too small and you expect to find your key in n/2 = 1.5 attempts?

Comment: ^ Nope to that previous theory; expanding the array up to 10 rows doesn't cause a difference. My machine does the 100K iterations for both forms of code in 19.2s.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ["one"=>"un", "two"=>"deux", "three"=>"trois"];
foreach ($array as $index=>$value){
    echo $index . ' : ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed simple:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    echo " ";
    echo $value;
    echo "<br />";
}
```